# Hibernate cascade delete via embeddable primary key

Tags: hibernate, cascade

HI I have a PK that consists of an embeddable object.

It's made out of two constraints

@ManyToOne
SpecificType1 spec;
@ManyToOne
SpecificType1 spec;

So basically a mapping table between two objects.

I'd like to cascade delete based on the object that implements this embeddable PK.

I added @Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}) on SpecificType1, but it just won't execute the cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cascade does not make sense.

You have many `Foo` entities having the same `SpecificType1` (ManyToOne). And you're configuring Hibernate so that if you delete one of the `Foo` instances, it also deletes the `SpecificType1`. This would obviously leave all the other `Foo` entities with an association to an unexisting `SpecificType1`, which would break the foreign key constraint, and cause a rollback.